# draggable helper going behind table in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have been using Jquery Draggable for the rows which has been implemented by JqGrid.But when the item is dragged the Drag Helper is not going out of table boundary. I can drop the item. But the Helper item is not showing outside the table during the drag process.

How can i make it possible to show the Helper on top of JqGrid table?

Code snippet:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var dragText='';
    $("#list2 tr").draggable({                  
            helper:helpText,
            cursor : 'move',
            revert : 'invalid'
    });
    function helpText(){
            $("#tree li span").droppable();
            console.log('drag');
           dragText=$(this).find("td:nth-child(5)").text();
            return'<div id="draggableHelper">' + dragText + '</div>';
    };
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the helper div to be appended to the html body (or any other containment area you want) so it could float around anywhere in containment area.

a sample code:

```
$("#list2 tr").draggable({
    helper: function () {
        return jQuery(this).clone().appendTo('body').css({
            'zIndex': 5
        });
    },
    cursor : 'move',
    revert : 'invalid'
})
```

Comment: Hey, I am getting the whole table row as Helper. But i was only text as shown in screenshot. And Droppable is not working when I drop the item now. Any work around for that?

Comment: Hey Got it... !!! Modified code to :- return jQuery(this).find("td:nth-child(5)").clone().appendTo('body').css({'zIndex': 99})

Comment: By the way. Why is $("#tree li span").droppable(); inside callback. If $("#tree li span") is bot dynamic you can do it outside helper callback scope..